# What happens if I create a class with main thread in android studio

Tags: java, android-studio

If I create a java class with the main method within Android Studio does it affect my activities both `mainActivity` and others and how does it affect them?
I am a bit new to Android studio ...

Comment: Could you be more specific?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean the `main` method. Android gives no special meaning to a method called "main". If you put a main method in any of your classes it'll just be ignored, unless you call it yourself.